# Ruby: how does constant-lookup work in instance_eval/class_eval?

Tags: ruby, constants, instance-eval

I'm working my way through Pickaxe 1.9, and I'm a bit confused by constant-lookup in instance/class_eval blocks. I'm using 1.9.2.

It seems that Ruby handles constant-lookup in *_eval blocks the same way it does method-lookup:

1. look for a definition in receiver.singleton_class (plus mixins);
2. then in receiver.singleton_class.superclass (plus mixins);
3. then continue up the eigenchain until you get to `#<Class:BasicObject>`;
4. whose superclass is Class;
5. and then up the rest of the ancestor chain (including `Object`, which stores all the constants you define at the top-level), checking for mixins along the way

Is this correct? The Pickaxe discussion is a bit terse.

Some examples:

```
class Foo
  CONST = 'Foo::CONST'
  class << self
    CONST = 'EigenFoo::CONST'
  end
end

Foo.instance_eval { CONST } # => 'EigenFoo::CONST'
Foo.class_eval { CONST } # => 'EigenFoo::CONST', not 'Foo::CONST'!
Foo.new.instance_eval { CONST } # => 'Foo::CONST'
```

In the class_eval example, Foo-the-class isn't a stop along Foo-the-object's ancestor chain!

And an example with mixins:

```
module M
  CONST = "M::CONST"
end
module N
  CONST = "N::CONST"
end

class A
  include M
  extend N
end

A.instance_eval { CONST } # => "N::CONST", because N is mixed into A's eigenclass
A.class_eval { CONST } # => "N::CONST", ditto
A.new.instance_eval { CONST } # => "M::CONST", because A.new.class, A, mixes in M
```

Answer (score 1):

In 1.9.2 the constant lookup has changed **again** to be equivalent to the 1.8.7 behavior.

```
class A
  class B
    class C
    end
  end
end

A.class_eval { B } # => NameError
A.instance_eval { B } # => NameError
A.new.instance_eval { B } # => A::B
```

Basically, the constants are quasi-lexically scoped. This USED to be different between 1.9.x and 1.8.x branches, and it made library cross compatibility a pain, so they changed it back.

[Yehuda Katz's (successful) appeal to restore 1.8 behavior](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/191672)

Comment: Note: As of Ruby 2.3, this is no more true.

Answer (score 0):

Constants are effectively lexically scoped so you cannot access them short hand outside of the module hierarchy within which they are defined. There is a good explanation [here](http://valve.github.io/blog/2013/10/26/constant-resolution-in-ruby/) and slightly off topic but a good read [here](http://blog.honeybadger.io/understanding-ruby-refinements-and-lexical-scope/).