# Accessing a constant

Tags: ruby, constants

Why can't I access 'B' in the following from 'A' but can from the main environment?

```
module A; end
A.instance_eval{B=1}

B #=> 1
A::B #=> uninitialized
```

Comment: What version of Ruby? http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/181646 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015947/ruby-how-does-constant-lookup-work-in-instance-eval-class-eval

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idiomatic way to do this would be

```
 A.const_set(:B, 1)
 A::B #=> 1
```

As to why it doesn't work, in Ruby 1.8 and 1.9.2+ (it was different in 1.9.1), constant lookup is lexically scoped. I found a good [blog post](http://jfire.posterous.com/constant-lookup-in-ruby) with an explanation. To quote:

> Note that these rules apply to constant definition as well as lookup.
>   In 1.8 and 1.9.2, a constant defined in a class_evaluated block will
>   be defined in the enclosing lexical scope, rather than the scope of
>   the receiver.

The same is also true for `instance_eval`.

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation of `instance_eval`](http://apidock.com/ruby/BasicObject/instance_eval) (emphasis mine):

> Evaluates a string containing Ruby source code, or the given block, within the context of the receiver (obj). **In order to set the context, the variable self is set to obj while the code is executing**, giving the code access to obj’s instance variables.

Nothing more is done here. In particular, the constant assignment runs in the enclosing context of the block. Observe:

```
irb(main):001:0> module A
irb(main):002:1>   module B; end
irb(main):003:1>   B.instance_eval { C = 1 }
irb(main):004:1> end
=> 1
irb(main):006:0> A::C
=> 1
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Because . . .

. . . constants that are not defined within a class or module are given global scope.

What matters for constant definition is the enclosing lexical scope, not the current receiver or the value of `self`.

Answer (score 1):

```
module A; end
A.class_eval{B=1}
B # Undefined
A::B # 1
```

As for why it works, I'm not really sure. I occasionally use metaprogramming like this when creating very meta frameworks such the Small Eigen Collider, but not in day-to-day work.

Comment: Are you sure with this? As far as I tested on irb 1.9.3, it gives the same result as with `instance_eval`.

Comment: I tried it on 1.9.1 . Sorry for not mentioning that, I didn't expect it to change between tiny versions.

Comment: That's interesting. Then, how does `instance_eval` work in 1.9.1? Is it like how I reported?

Comment: @sawa Both `B` and `A::B` are undefined.

Comment: Wow, that's complicated. I wish someone asks this on the Ruby site.

Comment: @sawa: When using `instance_eval`, the constant will be assigned to `A`'s eigenclass in 1.9.1. You can use `(class << A; self; end)::B` to retrieve it.