# What is the context of a constant definition for a constant defined in a block in ruby?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Here's a question to bamboozle your noodle.

It seems there's a difference between method declaration and constant declaration in a block that is evaluated using `class_eval` with a class as the receiver. Here's some code that demonstrates the discrepancy:

```
module X
  def save_block(&block)
    @block = block
  end
end

module Y
  extend X
  save_block do
    SOME_CONSTANT = 1
    def meth
      "a method"
    end
  end
  def self.included(m)
    m.class_eval &@block
  end
end

class Z
  include Y
end

class W
  include Y
end
```

Executing this code, at least in Ruby 1.9.3, results in the following error:

```
warning: already initialized constant SOME_CONSTANT
```

Which I didn't expect. Consider first where `meth` is located:

```
Z.instance_methods(false)
=> [:meth]

W.instance_methods(false)
=> [:meth]
```

And `Y` doesn't have any instance methods:

```
Y.instance_methods(false)
=> []
```

This makes sense because the block is executed with `Z` and `W` as the receivers of `class_eval`. However, the constants are different, hence the error message, as shown here:

```
Y.constants(false)
=> [:SOME_CONSTANT]

Z.constants(false) 
=> []

W.constants(false)
=> []
```

Here, the constant ends up getting defined in `Y` (for some bizarre reason) and thus when the block is executed a second time, the constant, `SOME_CONSTANT` is already defined.

I very much look forward to some enlightenment.

**Update (2012/11/19):**

As @phoet pointed out below (the the response to my comment to his answer), constants are defined in the [lexical scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29#Lexical_scoping) of the block, that is to say, in the scope where the block is originally defined. In my example, this would be Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as described in this question [Accessing a constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10078744/accessing-a-constant) constant handling is within it's "lexical scope", meaning the context they are defined, not the context they are executed.

Comment: Constants are definitely not created at parase time. For example, if I execute `Y.constants(false)` before Z or W are defined, but after Y is defined, then I get the empty array `[]`. The block must be evaluated for the constant to be defined. I'm just not sure why the constant gets attached to Y instead of Z and W individually.

Comment: yeah, you are right. it's about scoping: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10078744/accessing-a-constant

Comment: If you update your answer, to reflect this, I'll accept it (I already added a note to my original question).