# Why direct assignment of constant within Class.new code block does not work

Tags: ruby, constants

Consider the following code:

```
c1 = Class.new { ANSWER = 42 }
#⇒ #<Class:0x00556c8fc09c60> < Object
c1.constants
#⇒ []
c1.new.class.constants
#⇒ []
c1.new.singleton_class.constants
#⇒ []
Object.constants.grep /ANS/
#⇒ [:ANSWER]
```

The constant seems to be defined on the `Object`. But with the explicit call to `const_set` the constant assignment works perfectly:

```
c2 = Class.new { const_set :ANSWER, 42 }
#⇒ #<Class:0x00556c8f7f3568> < Object
c2.constants
#⇒ [:ANSWER]
c2.new.class.constants
#⇒ [:ANSWER]
c2.new.singleton_class.constants
#⇒ [:ANSWER]
```

My question is: **what prevents the constant from being properly assigned on `Class.new` instance in the first snippet**?

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10078744/accessing-a-constant

Comment: @MarcinKołodziej seems like the [last answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10078954/2035262) sheds a light on he issue and the lexical scope matters here. We seem to need an explicit `class` keyword to open the new scope.

Comment: Which is honestly insane, but taking for granted `define_method` works similar contrary to explicit `def`, maybe that’s done on purpose.

Comment: `Class.new { self::ANSWER = 42 }` does the trick, or `Class.new { 
 |c| c::ANSWER = 42 }` if you want to be more explicit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[There are three implicit contexts in Ruby](https://blog.yugui.jp/entry/846):

- `self` (the context for receiverless message sends, and instance variables)
- the *default definee* (the context for `def` method definition expressions without an explicit target, i.e. `def bar` instead of `def foo.bar`)
- the *default constant definition point*

Unfortunately, while the article I linked to above lists all three of them, it only discusses the first two and defers the default constant definition point to a later article, which was never written.

Anyway, it is important to keep those three contexts in mind, and be aware of when they change and when they don't.

In particular, a block *only* changes the *lexical context* and **nothing else**. A block does not change `self`, it does not change the *default definee* and it does not change the *default constant definition point*.

However, there are some methods whose *explicit* purpose it is to change one or more of those three contexts.

The `*_eval` family of methods changes `self` (context #1) and the default definee (context #2), but it does *not* change the default constant definition point (context #3). In particular, all `*_eval` (`*_exec`) methods set `self` to the receiver. The `instance_*` versions set the default definee to the receiver's singleton class, the `module_*` and `class_*` versions set the default definee to the receiver.

However, the default constant definition point is *not* changed, so constant definition (and lookup) works just as before: definitions go to the nearest lexically enclosing module definition, lookup starts at the nearest lexically enclosing module definition and proceeds lexically *outwards* and dynamically *upwards*-by-inheritance.

As far as I could find, the *only construct* that changes the default constant definition point is a `module`/`class` definition.

Comment: Thank you. This answer is outstanding as usual.

Answer (score 1):

The doc for [Class::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Class.html#method-c-new) states, "If a block is given, it is passed the class object, and the block is evaluated in the context of this class like `class_eval`.", meaning that

```
c = Class.new { ANSWER = 42 }
```

is equivalent to

```
c = Class.new
c.class_eval  { ANSWER = 42 }
```

`class_eval` creates the constant at top-level, because it was called on `c` at top-level. `c.class_eval  { ANSWER = 42 }` is in fact the same as

```
ANSWER = 42
```

which creates a constant on `Object`.

```
Object::ANSWER
  #=> 43
```

Here it is the other way around.

```
NUMBER = 43
Object::NUMBER
  #=> 43

c = Class.new
c.const_set(:NUMBER, 48)
c::NUMBER
  #=> 48
c.class_eval { puts NUMBER }
43
```

Here's another example.

```
class F
  class G; end
  G.class_eval { HIPPO = 5 }
end

F::HIPPO
  #=> 5
F::G::HIPPO
  #=> #NameError (uninitialized constant F::G::HIPPO)
  #   Did you mean?  F::HIPPO
```

However,

```
class F
  class G
    class_eval { HIPPO = 5 }
  end
end

F::HIPPO
  #=> NameError (uninitialized constant F::HIPPO)
F::G::HIPPO
  #=> 5
```

Readers: see [Module#class_eval](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-class_eval) and [this discussion](https://cirw.in/blog/constant-lookup) about constant lookup using `class_eval` (the complement of creating a constant). (Search for `"class_eval"`).

Comment: _“and the block is evaluated in the context of this class ”_ —is exactly why I would expect `ANSWER` to be defined on `c`, not on `Object`.