# How is constant accessibility determined?

Tags: ruby, constants

Ruby seems to have undergone changes several times with respect to constant accessibility. For Ruby 1.9.2, there is description regarding constant accessibility in the question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015947/ruby-how-does-constant-lookup-work-in-instance-eval-class-eval), but what is written there is not true anymore.

In Ruby 2.3, if I have a constant defined in a class:

```
class A
  Foo = :a
end
```

I cannot access it via `instance_eval` or `class_eval`:

```
A.new.instance_eval{Foo} # => error
A.class_eval{Foo} # => error
A.instance_eval{Foo} # => error
```

although I can access it from the class body:

```
class A; Foo end # => :a
```

How does constant accessibility work as of Ruby 2.3? If possible, please explain the historical changes of constant accessibility in Ruby and the arguments that led to them.

Comment: Also, `A.const_get :Foo #=> :a` and `A.class_eval "Foo"
 => :a` (2.3).

Comment: @CarySwoveland Right. But those are more like real/core uses of the `eval` varieties, parsing from a string/symbol. And especially, `const_get` is designed precisely to do that; if it wouldn't work that way, it would be a huge problem.

Comment: I’d address this issue to ruby parser, not to constant lookup. BTW, 2.1 works like 2.3. Anyway: `A.instance_eval { |a| a::Foo } # => :a` and 
`A.instance_eval { self::Foo } # => :a`, while `A.instance_eval { Foo } # => error`. The latter two must behave the same way, that is why I blame the parser.

Comment: The more I think about this, the more I am convinced that is a matter of variables scoping: `C = :outer ; class A ; C = :inner ; end` ⇒ 
`A.class_eval { C } #⇒ :outer` and `A.instance_eval { C } #⇒ :outer`. I believe this could lead to ambiguity in the example provided, that’s why it was finally made this way. Note, that in `A.class_eval "C"` there is no such ambiguity, and it is interpreted as you excepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constant lookup in Ruby uses [lexical scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15119724/ruby-lexical-scope-vs-inheritance) which traverses the current scope and containing modules. The lookup path can be viewed via `Module.nesting`

```
> module Out
>   module In
>     puts Module.nesting
>   end
> end
Out::In # gets searched for a given constant first
Out
```

The lookup remains the same inside a block to enable closure behavior, even for `class_eval`.

However, in Ruby 1.9, the receiver for `instance_eval`, `instance_exec`,
`class_eval`, and `class_exec` was prepended to the lookup path, which means all constant references would be looked up in the receiver's scope first.

Yehuda Katz raised an [issue](http://marc.info/?l=ruby-core&m=125843152426198&w=2) citing significant breakage:

> Consider the case of RSpec:
>
> ```
> describe "Date" do   
>   it "equals itself" do
>     Date.today.should == Date.today   
>   end 
> end
> ```
>
> If we use dynamic scope first, then if RSpec adds Spec::Date, it will
>   suddenly break this spec. Lexical scope is more intuitive, and is
>   expected by many normal uses today.

The behaviour was subsequently [reverted](http://marc.info/?l=ruby-core&m=125964634407351&w=2) back to 1.8.

Answer (score 4):

<sup>Note: Below answer is based on Ruby 2.2, have not verified on 2.3</sup>

As per documentation of [`Module#class_eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-class_eval)

> Evaluates the string or block in the context of mod, **except that when
>   a block is given, constant/class variable lookup is not affected.**

Though below code errored out,

```
A.class_eval{Foo} # uninitialized constant Foo (NameError)
```

following works where a string is being `eval`ed.

```
A.class_eval("Foo") #=> :a
```

It also seems that Constant requires Module name or Class name for it to be evaluated properly.  Below works:

```
A.class_eval{self::Foo} #=> :a
```

So, does these:

```
A.new.instance_eval {self.class::Foo} #=> :a
A.instance_eval {self::Foo} #=> :a
```